# Set custom refresh rate for Sway (Wayland)

Tags: graphics, wayland, nouveau, sway

I know it's possible to set a custom refresh rate and resolution using Xorg (xrander) configurations. But I do not know how to do the same in Wayland/Sway using Nouveau drivers on an Nvidia-GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `swaymsg -t get_outputs` to list available resolutions and refresh rates.

Then add it to your sway config:

```
output DVI-I-1 mode 1920x1080@143.996002Hz position 0,0
```